# How to create a new column where each row is a value from another column (B-E), conditional on another column that has the name of the column (B-E)?

Tags: r, data.table

Sorry for the convoluted title! Here is an example:

I would like to create the column `new_col`. `new_col` is constructed by searching in `colA` for the (partial) name of another column in the dataset. I would like to fill `new_col` with the value in the column referred to in `colA`, for each row.

```
colA colB colC
B     1    5 
C     3    6
B     4    7
```

Adding in `new_col`

```
colA colB colC new_col
B     1    5    1
C     3    6    6
B     4    7    4
```

How can I do this? I know how to do this looping through each row one by one, but is there a better way to do this, using R, especially if I have a lot of data? (for example, a data.table solution)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sapply(1:nrow(df),function(x){df[x,paste0("col",df$colA[x])]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove additional text from the column name so that the value in `colA` matches the names.

```
sub('col', '', names(df))
#[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

You can use `match` to construct a column index and use this as an index to subset.

```
df$new_col <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df), match(df$colA, sub('col', '', names(df))))]
df
#  colA colB colC new_col
#1    B    1    5       1
#2    C    3    6       6
#3    B    4    7       4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(colA = c("B", "C", "B"), colB = c(1L, 3L, 4L), 
    colC = 5:7), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```